# Determine the minimum of three floats with the least amount of comparisons possible

Tags: c++, optimization

So I have a little optimization problem. I need to determine which of three floats is the minimum in as little operations/comparisons as possible. Here's what I have:

```cpp
if (x < y) {
    if (x < z) {
        // Do X related code
    } else {
        // Do Z related code
    }
} else {
    if (y < z) {
        // Do Y related code
    } else {
        // Do Z related code. (Duplicate!!!!)
    }
}
```

This method always requires ONLY two comparisons. This is decently important because this is run in a very tight loop and can happen hundreds or thousands of times per frame. So I would also like to avoid allocating more variables too.

As you can see, we have a little duplicate there for the Z related code. The code is short, like 3 lines short, but it's still bugging me that I have to duplicate it.

Is it possible to do this with still only two comparisons, no additional allocations, and not have to duplicate the Z code?

Thanks,

Comment: Put the code in a function.

Comment: Can’t! The block modifies variables in the rest of the loop. Plus calling a function would be slower than just doing an extra comparison. Inlining the function doesn't improve much because now I've just made the function even messier by adding extra unnecessary short functions. Macros would be even worse for cleanliness

Comment: Why not use `std::min`? Are you planning on being more efficient than that?

Comment: Any modern compiler will make this as optimal as it can be.

Comment: @cigien We don't care about the actual values of x y or z. We care about just knowing which one is smallest.

Comment: @drescherjm While the compiler will optimize it away, it’s still a little bit annoying because of my DRY compulsions. If this is not possible to do then I suppose I'll have to leave it that way :)

Comment: You don't want to repeat code, but also don't want to use a function? Seems a bit contradictory to be honest.

Comment: How do you feel about a good old `goto`? (lol jk)

Comment: Introduce `bool` flags, set them inside `if`s, and then use them to select branches. The compiler is likely to optimize additional comparisons away if this is really beneficial for the performance.

Comment: What's wrong with storing the min of x and y, then comparing that with z?

Comment: @cigien I can’t use a function. Several variables are modified and the outer function may exit early. Just to do the exit early function would require an additional comparison, not to mention the cost of passing all the modified variables as pointers to the function. I can use a macro — but that's ugly!

Comment: A function is possible if you pass it pointers or references to any variables/arrays that need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to introduce `bool` flags first, and then select a branch by checking their values. For example, GCC 9.1 (with `-O1` and above) [produces](https://godbolt.org/z/8GJBsi) the same assembly code for

```
if (x < y) {
    if (x < z)
        fx();
    else
        fz();
} else {
    if (y < z)
        fy();
    else
        fz();
}
```

and

```
bool bx = false;
bool by = false;
if (x < y)
    bx = (x < z);
else
    by = (y < z);

if (by)
    fy();
else if (bx)
    fx();
else
    fz();
```

Depending on what the actual XYZ-related code is, this optimization might not be applied by the compiler (and maybe for a good reason). You can look through the generated assembly and benchmark both versions.